# Stability conditions of coherent sheaves on abelian 3-folds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

My work for now consists on understanding stability conditions of coherent sheaves on abelian 3-folds. I have the book by D. Huybrechts (the geometry of moduli spaces of sheaves), But I would like to have more resources which focus on properties of coherent sheaves. If it is possible, can you please tell me some references, also any suggestion and comment is welcome.

Comment: there has recently been big progress here. See Maciocia, Piyaratne "Fourier-Mukai transforms and Bridgeland stability conditions on abelian threefolds" I and II and "The space of stability conditions for abelian threefolds, and some Calabi-Yau threefolds" by Beyer, Macri and Stellari. (I am not an expert and so could have missed an important reference, but you certainly should be aware of these papers.)

Answer (score 1):

The question might be a bit vague. Certainly there are excellent references online on stability conditions. The first which comes to mind is the most elementary and is [by Arend Bayer](http://www.phys.vt.edu/mp10/lect-notes/bayer/dc-lecture-notes.pdf). If you are already familiar with all of that, these notes [by Daniel Huybrechts](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1745) go deeper into the subject. These are notes from a lecture series delivered in Cambridge, which was [recorded on video](http://www-old.newton.ac.uk/programmes/MOS/seminars/index.html). Also, I find the [original paper](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v166-n2-p01.pdf) by Bridgeland quite readable.